# Redirect from ActionFilterAttribute to Custom Error Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a login system, which means if an unauthorized user (not logged in) is trying to visit an authorized page an 401 error (Unauthorized) should be displayed, but it redirects to an incorrect error page I also have which is 404 NotFound.

**It shows "NotFound" when it should "Unauthorized".** [image]

UserAuthenticationFilter

```
public class UserAuthenticationFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            // Check session is empty then set as result is HttpUnauthorizedResult
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(filterContext.HttpContext.Session["UserId"])))
            {
                filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
            }
        }
        public void OnAuthenticationChallenge(AuthenticationChallengeContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.Result == null || filterContext.Result is HttpUnauthorizedResult)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
                {
                    ViewName = "Unauthorized"
                };
            }
        }

    }
```

ErrorController

```
[HandleError]
    public class ErrorController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Error()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult NotFound()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult Unauthorized()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Web.config

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On">
      <error statusCode="401" redirect="~/Error/Unauthorized"/>
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/NotFound"/>
    </customErrors>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms timeout="2800"></forms>
    </authentication>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <globalization uiCulture="en-US" />
  </system.web>
```

Comment: Try removing "NotFound" action method and see whats the result is @Zagros

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/292 . .  have a look at this

Comment: I didn't manage to figure out the problem. It still navigating to Not Found when it should navigate to NonAuthorized?